# exact matches in elasticsearch (including whitespaces)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 6.5 and I have the following documents

```
{"id": 1, "type": "a"}
{"id": 2, "type": "a b"}
```

Type mapping looks like this

```
"type": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

Desired behavior:

- when I query by type `a` I would like to get only the document with id `1`
- when I query by type `a b` I would like to get only the document with id `2`

What I have tried:

- query_string_query: if the searched value is between double quotes then: if input=`a` then I get both `1` and `2`; if input=`a b` then I get only `2`
- term query
- match query

I probably tried various other solutions suggested on stackoverflow but so far nothing worked as expected. Also please note the version of ES, in newer versions we have other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add .keyword to the type field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after type field). Try out this below query -

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "type.keyword":"a b"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65327197",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "type": "a b"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you also give ma a hint on how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: @tzortzik for case insensitive and exact match you can use `lowercase` normalizer of elasticsearch. You need to create an index with the custom settings for the same.